# Spanning forest, maximal edge set and minimal cut

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $F \subseteq E$ an edge set. Proof that $G(F)$  is a spanning forest iff $E \backslash F$ is an inclusion-wise maximal edge set which doesn't include an inclusion-wise minimal cut of $G$.

I need to prove this equivalence for my exercise but I'm lacking the approach for a solution. On top of that, I find it hard to even understand what this statement means in a concrete visualisation.

Comment: What about the case $F=\emptyset$? Then $(V,F)=(V,\emptyset)$ is a forest, $F\subseteq E,$ and $E\setminus F=E.$ Can you prove that $E$ is "an inclusion-wise maximal edge set which doesn't include an inclusion-wise minimal cut of $G$"? I'm not exactly sure what the quoted statement means, but it seems unlikely that it can be proved, seeing as $E$ seems to be a completely general edge set.